# Click on 'Load More' in a loop till page is displayed fully

Tags: jquery, regex, powershell, match

I need to fetch all names from this web-page `https://www.xxx.com/search/all?name=sporanox`

On my webpage, I have a button 'Load More' which essentially means that there are some more items to be displayed on screen.

HTML source of Load More button is as follows :

```
a href="#" data-number="1" data-size="15" data-url="/search/paginate?name=sporanox" class="pgntnCntnrBar btn btn-primary">Load More</a><div class="loading-icon v2 hide"></div>
```

Hence I need some way in PowerShell where Script can click on 'Load More' by itself in a loop so that whole page is displayed.

I am not well versed with PowerShell and read somewhere that a `click()` method can be used, so I did the following:

```
$regex = [RegEx]'">Load More</a>'
$url = ‘https://www.xxx.com/search/all?name=sporanox’
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$content = $wc.DownloadString($url)
$a = $regex.Matches($content) | ForEach-Object { $_.Groups[0].Value }
$a.click()
```

But I am getting an error:

> Method invocation failed because System.String does not contain a method named 'click'

---

**Update :**
I could find following way to click. But do not know how to put it in loop.

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.visible=$true
$ie.navigate2('https://www.xxx.com/search/all?name=sporanox')
while($ie.Busy) {Start-Sleep 1}
$links = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('A')
$yt = $links | where {$_.innerText -eq 'Load More'}
$yt.click()
```

Comment: Your first example would never work as is since you are manipulating a string that is no longer connected to the website. Why does the second example need to be in a loop? Oh.. the load more keeps on coming... i think i get it.

Comment: I could not understand your comment. Your first example...connected to website. How is it so ?

Comment: The method is called `DownloadString`. In your first example you are working with just text. Yes you find the match but you are not working with the website at that point. You are just working with the string you downloaded which is why you get the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update, looks like they are hiding the 'Load More' button once they are done. So an additional check is necessary. Code updated:

```
$ie = New-Object -COMObject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.visible = $true
$site = $ie.Navigate('https://www.xxx.com/search/all?name=za')
$ie.ReadyState

while($true)
{
    while ($ie.Busy -and $ie.ReadyState -ne 4){ sleep -Milliseconds 100 }
    try { 

        $numTries = 0
        $link = $null
        while ($link -eq $null -and $numTries -le 5)
        {
            $link = $ie.Document.get_links() | where-object {$_.innerText -eq 'Load More'}
            if ($link -eq $null)
            {
                sleep -Milliseconds 1000
            }

            $numTries++
        }
        if ($link -ne $null)
        {
            if ($link.clientHeight -eq 0)
            {
                break
            }
            [Void]$link.click()
        }
        else
        {
            break
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        break
    }
}
```

PS. I wanted to use `$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('A')` but I get an exception.

Comment: Sometimes it is not working. Maybe connection at my end is slow and   that may be single reason for it. For example : https://www.healthkartplus.com/search/all?name=za is not working

Comment: Yes I was able to reproduce it. Looks like `get_links` didn't finish and so `$link` remained $null. See if this new version helps